# Zip select files from root directory maintaining the directory structure

Tags: python, zip

I have a list of files written to a text file using command line(extracted list of files with a specific extension). I want to write these files to a zip file but not all files to a root directory but maintain the directory structure.

Comment: [Please don't add "solved" to your title or question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/116105/248627). Instead, [mark an answer correct by clicking on the checkmark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/248627). You can also [add your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and accept it if none of the ones you received solved your problem.

Comment: And please don't add fake "tags" to your title. Just use real tags.

Comment: Self-answering is great, but please make sure to ask an on-topic question (you can see what's on-topic in the [help/on-topic]). "Give me code to do X" is not on-topic. What specific part of this were you having trouble with before writing the code in your answer?

Comment: I had tried a few other solutions provided here itself, but they created a zip file with all the files at the root, and not inside their respective folders. I was midway writing the question, when I decided to try the solution I shared below and used the self-answer feature in SO itself to answer the question.

Also will keep your suggestions in mind(regarding "solved" tag and about being more specific). Thanks.

Comment: FYI I rolled back your latest edit, as there's no way to know what other SO solutions you're referring to. It really doesn't add to the question. What you really need to add is your specific work: code, errors, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I was able to achieve this  using the code below.

```
import os
import zipfile

f = open("notebooks.txt", "r")
lines =  f.readlines()
lines
with zipfile.ZipFile('file.zip', 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) as zipf:
    for line in lines:
        line = line.rsplit("\n",1)[0]
        print(os.path.isfile(line))
        try:
            zipf.write(line)
            print(line,"passed")
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            pass
```